# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'. > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C\path\.android\.android\build-cache

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C\users\Rahul.android.android\build-cache

I have tried searching a lot to get this error fixed. Even reinstalled Android Studio in a different drive, but doesn't help. 
Any idea how to get this fixed?

Note - This happens even when I create a new project and try compiling it.

**Things I have tried :

1) Cleaning Project 

2) Invalidating Caches and restarting 

3) Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio in a different drive**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add ***android.enableBuildCache=false*** to ***gradle.properties*** file and that should fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler
Add to "Command-line Options":
-x :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies -x :app:mockableAndroidJar -x :app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources
Press "OK" and try to Rebuild Project again
```

have you tried above method ?

refer https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api/issues/21

Comment: Tried, didn't help :( 
That throws another error - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C\users\Rahul\.android\.android\build-cache\917b43703f121f570265fcdb969c81ccccb180bdad3e83fc91408e38425707f9\output

Comment: SDK may be damaged , try  downloading  it again  ? tried those ?

Comment: I completely removed all traces of Android Studio and reinstalled everything including the SDK which was done automatically by AS, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The .android file can be by default modified,created by the administrator, so 
right-click on the .android folder and then go to properties and set the permission for other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your classpath for **build** and **google** play!

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```